# Scrapy Python Crawler - Different Spider for each?

Tags: python, search, scrapy, web-crawler

I have a lot of different sites I want to scrape using scrapy. I was wondering what is the best way of doing this?

Do you use a different "project" for each site you want to scrape, or do you use a different "spider", or neither?

Any input would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

different PROJECT for each site is a **WORST** idea .

different SPIDER for each site is a **GOOD** idea .

if you can adjust multiple sites in one SPIDER (based of there nature) is a **BEST** idea .

but again all depends on your **Requirements**.

Comment: I'm not sure that have different spiders for every site could be a  bad idea, maybe if the websites are similar could be, but if there sites with big difference could be a problem because you need change the settings of each and maybe the middle ware too. I agree that depends of requirements. Maybe you need separate the site that use .asp and the other sites.